# partial derivative of cost function using chain rule

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I need to compute the partial derivative of the cost function of a neural network, with respect to $z_1$ and $z_2$. The cost function is defined below:

[image]

[image] [image]

In my attempt to do this:

[image]

I calculated both partial derivatives to be essentially the same, I'm not sure this is correct? if its not, could someone point me to where ive gone wrong. thanks - i apolgise for using pictures!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c=\ln(e^{z_1}+e^{z_2})-z_y$$
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial z_1}=\frac{e^{z_1}}{e^{z_1}+e^{z_2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial z_2}=\frac{e^{z_2}}{e^{z_1}+e^{z_2}}$$
remember with partial derivatives: it is the same as taking a derviative but you treat all other varables as constants so for each one we can say:
$$c=\ln(e^{z_1}+a_1)-a_2$$
$$\frac{dc}{dz_1}=\frac{e^{z_1}}{e^{z_1}+a_1}$$
now substitute in your other variables as the "constants"

---

The mistake you made in each step was the following:
$$\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z_1}=\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z_2}=0$$
Other than this your answer is correct :)